# wcf service which converts a pptx file into a video

Tags: wcf, powerpoint, wmv

I've written a windows application which converts a pptx file into a wmv.Now what i want to do is make this application as a service,so that it can run on server and when i consume I can send a pptx file,the convertions would be done in the server side and then the .wmv file would be sent back to my client.I've written some wcf services,but i'm no expert,far from it.My question is how the client and the server could transfer files
Thank you for your time